# Display two vocabularies

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type LAW with fields Title, law Category( Taxonomy Vocabulary) and Tags( Another taxonomy vocabulary) and last field is Description.

When Adding law content, I select in which category it belongs (lets say *Labor law*). I also add tags (e.g. *Condemnation*, *Judgement*) which are autocompleted as the default tags.

In view, I have displayed a list of all the categories, for example:

- Labor law
- Banking law
- Land law

When *Labor law* is clicked, I want a list of tags (*Condemnation*, *Judgement*) related to labor law; on clicking *Condemnation* or *Judgement* the nodes should be displayed.

Comment: You left out a very important part, which Drupal version are you using?

Comment: Hello @NoSssweat I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Maybe [views tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) will do

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar using normal taxonomy view for "category list" and made an exposed filter for "tags", and to show just tags related to the exact category i've used the "Views Selective Exposed Filters".